# Перенаправление ВСЕГО трафика с 1 айпи на другой

Tags: linux, ubuntu

В общем нужно чтобы весь трафик со всех портов перенаправлялся на другой айпи под теми же портами. Перерыл весь интернет не могу найти ответ на данный вопрос.

Это сервер который находится в другом дата центре. Немного точнее объясняю что хочу сделать. Это взять хетзнер поставить на него много игровых серверов на абсолютно разных портах. Далее через овх прогнать весь трафик чтобы в случае ддос атаки овх отфильтровал его своими системами ддос защиты.

Comment: Мне жаль, но в текущей формулировке вопрос непонятен. Ну, Вам то он понятен. А вот мне - нет. Думаю, что во первых, вы говорите про ВХОДЯЩИЙ трафик. во вторых, непонятно, где этот "второй айпи" находится: это другая сетевая карта в этом же компе? Другой комп в локалке? другой коп на обраной стороне земного шара? Опять таки, ЗАРАНЕЕ известны те самые "все порты"? а то, может, это 80, 443 и 8080. И тогда достаточно в Nginx сконфигурить proxy-pass. И еще - протоколы. tcp, udp - понятно. А как быть с acmp, например? Или на пинги в результате какой из IP отвечать должен?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Это сервер который находится в другом дата центре. Немного точнее объясняю что хочу сделать. Это взять хетзнер поставить на него много игровых серверов на абсолютно разных портах. Далее через овх прогнать весь трафик чтобы в случае ддос атаки овх отфильтровал его своими системами ддос защиты.

Comment: Задача интересная, но в случае DDOS атаки любая система основанная на "пользовательском" окружении (грубо говоря, запущенная на пользовательском компе, компе, который Вам "продают" в дата-центре) - просто "захлебнется" трафиком. Не зря на border'е стоят могучие циски, которые могут не подавиться 100 гигабайтами в секунду, и еще и фильтровать этот поток по определенным правилам. Но задача интересная. Но вообще, если порты известны заранее - можно просто запустить много - много Tcp-proxy?

Comment: @S.H. там игрушки и на многих будет udp, а на некоторых ещё возможно p2p с динамическими портами...

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб - не очень хорошее так как все клиенты будут прилетать с одного ip (вашего сервера) и возможна неправильная работа связи между игроками

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Более правильное решение это:

- купить второй адрес для проброса
- поставить туннель между системами по первому адресу
- назначить второй адрес на удаленном компе в этот тунель
- поставить основной шлюз удаленного компа в этот туннель
- выставить на внешнем интерфейсе проксиарп или просить роутинг в поддержке

Comment: несмотря на прямолинейность решения, его простота - прекрасна!